# Can' t make touchegg work on KDE

Tags: touchpad, kde, multi-touch, touchegg

I'm on a fresh install with KDE and just installed touchegg, but I don't seem to be able to make it work. I followed the installation instructions and copied the default config file but nothing happens even after rebooting. I tried to debug it by utilizing the --daemon flag but I get the following error:

```
$ touchegg --daemon
Touchégg v2.0.5.
Usage: touchegg [--daemon [start_threshold finish_threshold]] [--client]

Multi-touch gesture recognizer.
Touchégg is an app that runs in the background and transform the gestures you make on your touchpad into visible actions in your desktop.
For more information please visit:
https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg

Option          Meaning
 --daemon       Run Touchégg in daemon mode. This mode starts a service that gathers gestures but executes no actions
 --client       Connect to an existing Touchégg daemon and execute actions in your desktop
Without arguments Touchégg starts in client mode

Starting Touchégg in daemon mode
Starting daemon server...
Server started
A list of detected compatible devices will be displayed below:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Error initialising Touchégg: libinput open.
Touchégg should be run in daemon mode by systemd in order to be part of the 'input' group and have access to your touchpad.
If you prefer to run Touchégg without using systemd, please execute the following command:
$ sudo usermod -a -G input $USER
And reboot to solve this issue
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Also, trying to run it on client mode also doesn't work, it can't seem to connect to the daemon, it keeps loosing connection:

```
$ touchegg
Touchégg v2.0.5.
Usage: touchegg [--daemon [start_threshold finish_threshold]] [--client]

Multi-touch gesture recognizer.
Touchégg is an app that runs in the background and transform the gestures you make on your touchpad into visible actions in your desktop.
For more information please visit:
https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg

Option          Meaning
 --daemon       Run Touchégg in daemon mode. This mode starts a service that gathers gestures but executes no actions
 --client       Connect to an existing Touchégg daemon and execute actions in your desktop
Without arguments Touchégg starts in client mode

Starting Touchégg in client mode
Parsing you configuration file...
Using configuration file "/home/barzi/.config/touchegg/touchegg.conf"
Configuration parsed successfully
Connecting to Touchégg daemon...
Connection with Touchégg daemon lost. Reconnecting in 5 seconds...
Connection with Touchégg daemon lost. Reconnecting in 5 seconds...
```

The trackpad works and nothing else in the system seems to be broken, any input would be greatly appreciated! My guess is that the daemon can't be started for some reason.